# ag-grid no funciona llamando desde otro modulo?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular6

grid, funciona genial cuando lo implemento en el componente principal que es app-component.html a traves del app.module.ts, sin embargo da este error cuando implemento en otro modulo vehiculos.module.ts donde igual hago esto:
import { AgGridModule } from "ag-grid-angular";
en los imports:
AgGridModule.withComponents([])
sale este error:
Error: src/app/pages/vehiculos/vehiculos.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'ag-grid-angular' is not a known element:

1. If 'ag-grid-angular' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ag-grid-angular' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
   Espero su ayuda, gracias

Comment: Jose, podrías compartir el modulo principal y el modulo de vehiculos? Gracias

Comment: Baja el ng serve y vuelve a compilar.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo page que llama al modulo de vehiculos:

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
//nuevos
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
//componentes y modulos del sistema del sistema

import { PrincipalComponent } from './principal/principal.component';
import { VehiculosModule } from './vehiculos/vehiculos.module';
//import { AgGridModule } from '@ag-grid-community/angular';
import { AgGridModule } from "ag-grid-angular";
@NgModule({
  declarations: 
  [PrincipalComponent],  
  exports:[
    PrincipalComponent    
  ],
  imports: [       
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    VehiculosModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])
  ]
})
export class PagesModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modulo de vehiculos:

```
    import { VehiculosComponent } from './vehiculos.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AgGridModule } from "ag-grid-angular";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [VehiculosComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    // Grid
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])
  ]
})
export class VehiculosModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Componente vehiculo:

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehiculos',
  templateUrl: './vehiculos.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})

    export class VehiculosComponent implements OnInit {
      title = 'my-app';
    
      columnDefs = [
          { field: 'make' },
          { field: 'model' },
          { field: 'price'}
      ];
      rowData = [
          { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica2021', price: 35000 },
          { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo2021', price: 32000 },
          { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter2021', price: 72000 }
      ];
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    }
    

    <p>vehiculos works!</p>
    
    <ag-grid-angular
        style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
        class="ag-theme-alpine"
        [rowData]="rowData"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

ya se pudo solucionar el problema:

1. Se instalo los paquetes ag-grid comunity y ag-grid de los siguientes links:
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-community
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid
2. Faltaba una importacion en app.module.ts y se utilizo el ag-grid de comunity en el modulo principal:

   import { AgGridModule } from '@ag-grid-community/angular';
   imports: [
   AgGridModule.withComponents([])
3. En el modulo donde se llama al componente que utiliza ag-grid se importo la otra libreria:

   import { AgGridModule } from "ag-grid-angular";

   imports: [
   CommonModule,
   // Grid
   AgGridModule.withComponents([])
   ]
4. Finalmente en el componente donde se implemento ag-grid se utilizo esta importacion:

   import {Grid, GridOptions} from 'ag-grid/main';

Eso seria la solucion, gracias a Alexis narvaez por su ayuda.